# RAID Array - is this RAID broken?

Tags: raid, software-raid, windows-sbs-2011

```
Specifics:
Smart Array P140 in slot 4:  (Yellow !)
     Sata Array 2 - 2 logical drives.
        (rebuilding 0%)       Logical drive 1.  (Yellow !) 
        (ready for recovery)  Logical Drive 2.  (Yellow !)
```

Just took this over, SBS installed Monday after their other sbs 2011 had catastrophic failure. I re-purposed this HP Proliant ml150, installed SBS 2011. 
Email is up, all is good except i can find a reason why this is rebooting other than the disk. I ordered a new disk. Is this RAID issue causing reboot?

Nothing in Event viewer except "system shutdown unexpectedly"
I do not want to wipe OS, rebuild RAID, then re-install OS, unless I really have to. I never had a server shut down like this, normally I swap out bad drive, it rebuilds, end of story.

Is this shot?

This is the bad Drive:  1 TB SATA Drive at Port 2I: Bay 8

[image]

Comment: Does the rebuilding LD ever goes beyond 0% ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes it completes to 100% then starts over. I have the new drive ordered. The system keeps rebooting. I checked the events and it appears the system reboots when it hits a bad sector on that drive. I did more research and I am hoping the new drive fixes this. In the past I have not had a server reboot/shutdown like this when it had a bad drive, hence my apprehension.